# A special case of a mass is connected to a fixed piont and moves on a circular path problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A point mass $m$ is connected by a massless rod of length $l$ to a fixed point of support, now consider the mass moves on a circular path, rod has constant angle $θ$ with $e$ vertical, what's the angular velocity of motion around the circle.

If the $θ$ is constant, which is not change with time, should the angular velocity be zero? I think it should not be that simple!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See the image above. The angular velocity that the question is asking is in the horizontal plane thus it will be changing. with respect to a fixed point.

**The angle that the ball is making with the horizontal with respect to time**

**Image source- Google**

Comment: From your sketch: T sin(θ) = mr$ω^2$ and T cos(θ) = mg.  Divide the first equation by the second and solve for ω.  By the way, a vector representing the centripetal acceleration should point toward the center.

Comment: So it is pointing towards the centre.

Comment: This is in the frame of earth